# In var foo = true; the variable type for "foo" is what?

Tags: javascript, variables, var

```
var foo = true;
```

The variable type for `foo` is?

I've tried looking for this answer here and elsewhere to no avail.

Comment: if this is homework, the answer is null.

Comment: `typeof foo === 'boolean'`

Comment: Trick question: variables don't have a type, their values do. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a `boolean` type; that is, either `true` or `false`.

Comment: +1, but strictly, the type is [Boolean](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.3) (capital B), though the [*typeof*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3) operator returns "boolean".

Answer (score 2):

You can check it in the console:

```
var foo = true
> undefined
foo
> true
typeof foo
> "boolean"
```

Answer (score 1):

A `yes` or `no` / `true` or `false` / `1` or `0` is a boolean type variable, although Javascript doesn't really distinguish like most other languages do.

Comment: JS does distinguish between types of _values,_ but any variable can be assigned a value of any type. In JS `1` or `0` would be a number, not a boolean. `yes` or `no` would be a string.

Comment: They were examples of booleans in other languages. `0` is logically  equivalent to `false` and any other number is logically equivalent to `true`

Answer (score 0):

`foo` is a boolean.  You can see for yourself by doing this:

```
alert(typeof foo);
```